# Print out a line from a .txt file that has a keyword with parentheses in it

Tags: awk

I'm trying to print out lines of a bunch of output files that contain the characters "g(tot)" in them.

```
awk '/g(tot)/{print}' ./*/*.out
```

However, this is not printing anything, and it seems to be due to the parentheses around the "tot". How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(` and `)` are interpreted as special characters in a regular expression.

Escape `(` and `)` with a `\`:

```
 awk '/g\(tot\)/{print}' ./*/*.out
```

Answer (score 0):

`()` are specials characters in [RegEx](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp), they are for catching things in a group

> (…)
>   Parentheses are used for grouping in regular expressions, as in arithmetic. They can be used to concatenate regular expressions containing the alternation operator, ‘|’. For example, ‘@(samp|code){[^}]+}’ matches both ‘@code{foo}’ and ‘@samp{bar}’. (These are Texinfo formatting control sequences. The ‘+’ is explained further on in this list.)

So `/g(tot)/` actually matches `gtot` not `g(tot)`.
You need to escape it, like this `/g\(tot\)/`.
Also you can remove the part `{print}`, it's implied after a condition, so that sums to:

```
awk '/g\(tot\)/' ./*/*.out
```

However, for this simple task, I would suggest you to use `grep` instead:

```
awk 'g\(tot\)' ./*/*.out
```

And you can use `sed` too:

```
sed -n '/g\(tot\)/p' ./*/*.out
```